# when to use pre_save, save, post_save in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I see I can override or define `pre_save, save, post_save` to do what I want when a model instance gets saved.

Which one is preferred in which situation and why?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I shall try my best to explain it with an example:

[`pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save) and [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) are [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#signals) that are sent by the model. In simpler words, actions to take before or after the model's `save` is called.

A `save` [triggers the following steps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#what-happens-when-you-save)

- Emit a pre-save signal.
- Pre-process the data.
- Most fields do no pre-processing — the field data is kept as-is.
- Prepare the data for the database.
- Insert the data into the database.
- Emit a post-save signal.

Django does provide a way to override these signals.

Now,

`pre_save` signal can be overridden for some processing before the actual save into the database happens - Example: (I dont know a good example of where `pre_save` would be ideal at the top of my head)

Lets say you have a `ModelA` which stores reference to all the objects of `ModelB` which have **not** been edited yet. For this, you can register a `pre_save` signal to notify `ModelA` right before `ModelB`'s `save` method gets called (Nothing stops you from registering a `post_save` signal here too).

Now, `save` method (it is not a signal) of the model is called - By default, every model has a `save` method, but you can override it:

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    def save(self):
        #do some custom processing here: Example: convert Image resolution to a normalized value
        super(ModelB, self).save()
```

Then, you can register the `post_save` signal (This is more used that `pre_save`)

A common usecase is `UserProfile` object creation when `User` object is created in the system.

You can register a `post_save` signal which creates a `UserProfile` object that corresponds to every `User` in the system.

Signals are a way to keep things modular, and explicit. (Explicitly notify `ModelA` if i `save` or change something in `ModelB` )

I shall think of more concrete realworld examples in an attempt to answer this question better. In the meanwhile, I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The reason why `post_save` is used for `UserProfile` creation is because you can check whether the instance is `created` or not in post_save?(but not in pre_save, save)

Comment: You might want to add to the answer that pre_save or post_save have per se nothing to do with transactions. If you use get_or_create, or request level transactions, post_save is going to happen *inside* the transaction, not after it. Depending on the database you can use some of the post_commit signal implementations out there.

Answer (score 5):

```
pre_save
```

it's used before the transaction saves.

```
post_save
```

it's used after the transaction saves.

You can use `pre_save` for example if you have a `FileField` or an `ImageField`  and see if the `file` or the `image` really exists.

You can use `post_save` when you have an `UserProfile` and you want to create a new one at the moment a new `User` it's created.

Comment: for your `pre_save` example where you gave an example to check if file exists, which one is better to use signal or override the save method?? because I had problem to raise error to my form if I add validation in my `pre_save` signal.

Comment: @Keda87 If u r using a form I would go for overriding the validation function of the form.

Comment: nope! post_save is normally called in an atomic block. That means post_save happens *inside* the transaction.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget about recursions risk. 
If you use **post_save** method with **instance.save()** calling, instead of .update method, you should disconnect your **post_save** signal:

> Signal.disconnect(receiver=None, sender=None,
>   dispatch_uid=None)[source] To disconnect a receiver from a signal,
>   call Signal.disconnect(). The arguments are as described in
>   Signal.connect(). The method returns True if a receiver was
>   disconnected and False if not.
>
> The receiver argument indicates the registered receiver to disconnect.
>   It may be None if dispatch_uid is used to identify the receiver.

... and connect it again after.

**update()** method don't send pre_ and post_ signals, keep it in mind.