# What does pre_save and post_save do in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I was looking at the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save), about `pre_save` and `post_save` in django. The documentation really does not provide much substance, so what does `pre_save` and `post_save` do?

Comment: [Take a look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17658156/1628832) Hopefully it should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably skipped the introduction to [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#module-django.dispatch) in the docs:

> Django includes a “signal dispatcher” which helps allow decoupled
>   applications get notified when actions occur elsewhere in the
>   framework. In a nutshell, signals allow certain senders to notify a
>   set of receivers that some action has taken place.

Let's say you want to create a slug you have basically two options:

- [Override your model's save() method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/837835/630877)
- [Use the pre_save signal of your model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6462188/630877)

Comment: This is what I was confused about since I always override the `save` method, so I've never needed to use `pre_save` or `post_save`.

Comment: Overriding ```save()``` makes sense in that case. But as soon as your application grows larger and/or you need to take actions in regard to events of an pluggable app you use, signals become really useful.