# Django Model with math

Tags: django-models

Hey i have a problem with my django model.

i have one class like this:

```
class Test(model.Models):
    EV_Nr = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    Factor = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=False)

class Polter(models.Model):
    EV = models.ForeignKey(Test)
    RM = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    FM = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
```

My Problem:

- RM or FM has to be 0, if both >0, it's an error and can not be saved.
- but for example: RM = 10 and FM = 0. It's ok. 
  -> and the model has to check for the Factor in my Test Model and to do the
   following: FM = RM / Faktor(from Test Model) and save it in my databese.

How can i do this. After two days of searching I have no idea.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Seen https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save ?

Comment: yes, don't understand everything

Comment: well, one way to go is to check the values by pulling the relevant models and then saving if all is ok. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645801/when-to-use-pre-save-save-post-save-in-django